# docker-compose entrypoint restart not stateless

Tags: docker, docker-compose, stateless, docker-entrypoint

When I restart a container with `docker-compose up` with an entrypoint it's not stateless, it keep the context of the previous execution of the entrypoint.

docker-compose file:

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  test:
    image: debian:buster-slim
    entrypoint: ["/entrypoint.sh"]
    volumes:
      - ./entrypoint.sh:/entrypoint.sh
    command: ["echo", "100"]
```

entrypoint.sh file:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e
set -x

mkdir folder

exec "$@"
```

the first time it log

```
Creating network "test_compose_entrypoint_default" with the default driver
Creating test_compose_entrypoint_test_1 ... done
Attaching to test_compose_entrypoint_test_1
test_1  | + mkdir folder
test_1  | + exec echo 100
test_1  | 100
```

if I rerun a `docker-compose up` , the second time it log

```
Starting test_compose_entrypoint_test_1 ... done
Attaching to test_compose_entrypoint_test_1
test_1  | + mkdir folder
test_1  | mkdir: cannot create directory 'folder': File exists
test_compose_entrypoint_test_1 exited with code 1
```

If I run `docker-compose down` and then it work again, but impossible to run two times in a row.

Comment: You aren't restarting, that's because you see the error, your container is still running, to restart it you need to run `docker-compose restart`

Comment: I tried with a `docker-compose restart` same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, `docker-compose restart` tries re-running the main container process in the existing (stopped) container.  `docker-compose up` will default to reusing an existing container, if one exists with the right configuration, even if it's stopped.  This can be a problem for setups like what you show that have the reasonable expectation of starting in a clean environment.

One approach is to code defensively around the possibility of the directory already existing:

```sh
# Create `folder` only if it doesn't exist.  Could still fail
# if the directory is read-only, or if `folder` is a plain file.
test -d folder || mkdir folder
```

At a higher level, you could [`docker-compose rm`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/rm/) the existing container before re-launching it, or if you don't mind restarting everything, `docker-compose up --force-recreate`.  This approach isn't compatible with an automatic `restart:` policy, though.